# Left Align button in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue trying to get my button to left align with the a href.  I'm using bootstrap 3.

Can anyone assist?

```
<ul class="nav nav-list"> 
    <li class="nav-header">Type</li> 
    <li class="active"> 
    <button type="button" class="remove-filter" data-url="https://www.url.com">×</button>
        <a href="https://www.url.com/type:bananas"> Bananas </a> 
    </li> 
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the `pull-left` class to your button.

```
<button type="button" class="remove-filter pull-left" data-url="https://www.url.com">×</button>
```

You can find the snippet below

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-list"> 
    <li class="nav-header">Type</li> 
    <li class="active"> 
    <button type="button" class="remove-filter pull-left" data-url="https://www.url.com">×</button>
        <a href="https://www.url.com/type:bananas"> Bananas </a> 
    </li> 
<ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to add `"display: inline"` style to your `a` tag. Here is a working example.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="nav-header">Type</li>
  <li class="active">
    <button type="button" class="remove-filter" data-url="https://www.url.com">×</button>
    <a href="https://www.url.com/type:bananas" style="display: inline;"> Bananas </a> 
  </li>
  <ul>
```